# LTV formula calls for Avg Order Value * Purchase Frequency * Lifespan--what to do when Lifespan is less than 1 year and Purchase frequency is 1?

Tags: customer-lifetime-value

Let's say hypothetically that you have the following:

Looking at 5 years worth of data, we have in one group:

```
$200 Avg. Order Value
1 Purchase Frequency (1 lifetime purchase)
```

Using the lifespan for all customers, they average 0.5 years.

So when we look at the 1-time purchasers, and apply:

```
AOV * PF * Lifespan
```

Or:

```
LTV = $200 * 1.0 * 0.5 = $100
```

How would it make sense to someone that the LTV for a 1 time purchaser is less than their average order value?

Comment: I think you have your formula mixed up; the purchase frequency should be purchase per year. (which multiplied by lifespan gives you number of purchases (throughout lifespan). so i think you want to reconsider your calculations (and decide what stays approx same - purchases per year, or purchases per lifetime)...

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense because the AOV is per year and their lifetime is less than one year.